# Finder algorithm for "sort by name" options

Tags: swift, sorting, url, nsfilemanager, finder

Im use `NSFileManager` class to create collection of `URL`

```
let resourceKeys = Set<URLResourceKey>([.nameKey, .isDirectoryKey, .typeIdentifierKey])

let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: Array(resourceKeys), options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
let fileURLs = directoryContents.filter { (url) -> Bool in
    do {
        let resourceValues = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: resourceKeys)
        return !resourceValues.isDirectory! && resourceValues.typeIdentifier! == "public.jpeg"
    } catch { return false }
}
```

the next step Im sorted `fileURLs` collection by file name

```
let sortedFileURLs = fileURLs.sorted(by: { (URL1: URL, URL2: URL) -> Bool in
    return URL1.pathComponents.last! < URL2.pathComponents.last!
})
```

it works, but it's not the way as used Finder for "sort by name" options (another sorted result)
Please help! What algorithm used Finder for "sort by name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Finder-like sort order can be realized with [`localizedStandardCompare`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409742-localizedstandardcompare)

The documentation says:

> This method should be used whenever file names or other strings are presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is appropriate.

```
let sortedFileURLs = fileURLs.sorted{ $0.lastPathComponent.localizedStandardCompare($1.lastPathComponent) == .orderedAscending }
```

Note: `lastPathComponent` is preferable over `pathComponents.last!`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: instead of sorting the last path component better to sort using the URLResourceKey localizedNameKey. lastPathComponent would always return "pictures" while `localizedNameKey` would return the equivalent like "fotos" (Portuguese). OP should also use `localizedName` when displaying the file names to the user.